# Play framework - call controller in routes with Class parameter

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to create controller method and parametrize it with Class parameter to call it in routes:

```
GET     /api/res1           controllers.GenericController.index(clazz:Class = Res1.class)
GET     /api/res2           controllers.GenericController.index(clazz:Class = Res2.class)
```

and during compilation play shouts:

```
[error] /home/../workspace/repo/prototype/conf/routes:26: identifier expected but 'class' found.
[error] /home/../workspace/repo/prototype/conf/routes:26: ')' expected but '}' found.
```

why '}' ? and how to make my idea work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
/api/res1   controllers.GenericController.index(clazz: Class[_] = classOf[full.package.name.Res1])
```

Works just fine for me.

Comment: @quester oops, sorry, it is `classOf`, not `classof`. fixed now

Comment: and do you know why I got "'}' found"?

Comment: Scala's compilation messages are far from being perfect, you know :)